# How to sort data based on a parameter obtained from JSON through Getter and Setter multiples times using button

Tags: android, json, sorting

I want to save the ArrayList thatt is formed using getter and setter when I run my AsyncTask first time. It fetches json data and I uses that via getter and setter.

Now I have three sorting buttons. I want when first time date is populated it gets stored and I can apply sorting on array list and pass that sorted list to post execute.

What I did - used a boolen var to know if it's first run and modify it accordingly. I globally defined my array list and model.

Following is doInBackground()

```
protected List<service_detail_model> doInBackground(String... strings) {
        serviceModelList = new ArrayList<>();
if (!dataSet) {
    dataSet=true;
ServiceURL = ServiceURL + "type=" + type + "&city=" + city + "&orderby=" + orderby + "&origin=" + origin;
HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(ServiceURL);
Log.e("kkkk", jsonStr);
if (jsonStr != null) {
    try {
        JSONArray listArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
        for (int i = 0; i < listArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject serviceObject = listArray.getJSONObject(i);
            serviceModel = new service_detail_model();
            serviceModel.setName(serviceObject.getString("name"));
            serviceModel.setPhone(serviceObject.getString("phone"));
            serviceModel.setImage(serviceObject.getString("img"));
            serviceModel.setPer(serviceObject.getString("per"));
            serviceModel.setPrice(serviceObject.getInt("price"));
            serviceModel.setRating(serviceObject.getInt("rating"));
            serviceModel.setDist(serviceObject.getInt("dist"));
            serviceModelList.add(serviceModel);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
else{
    if (orderby.equals("location")) {
        Log.e("ll", String.valueOf(serviceModelList.get(0).getDist()));
        Collections.sort(serviceModelList, new Comparator<service_detail_model>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(service_detail_model o1, service_detail_model o2) {
                return o1.getDist() - o2.getDist();
            }
        });
    }
    else if (orderby.equals("price")) {
        Collections.sort(serviceModelList, new Comparator<service_detail_model>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(service_detail_model o1, service_detail_model o2) {
                return o1.getPrice() - o2.getPrice();
            }
        });
    }
    else if (orderby.equals("rating")) {
        Collections.sort(serviceModelList, new Comparator<service_detail_model>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(service_detail_model o1, service_detail_model o2) {
                return (int) (o1.getRating()*100 - o2.getRating()*100);
            }
        });
    }
}
        return serviceModelList;
    }
```

When I did debugging I found that list size is 0.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you clarify better what the result is, as opposed to what it's supposed to be? It'd make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Also, for future reference, please do check out [this guide on how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), if you haven't already.

Comment: I want that I should make HTTP request to my server just once. And I could use the result obtained with other button clicks.

Lets say I open the app, as onCreate gets called I executed Async task and populated the list viewusing getter and setter. Now I have 3 buttons and I want to sort the list obtained based on parameters. You can see the else condition. I am executing same async task with these buttons and the code is self explanatory.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add that in?